# Firebase VerifyIdToken in Java Spring backend

Tags: java, spring-boot, firebase-authentication, google-signin, firebase-admin

I've a mobile application that using Google sign and trying to verify the token in backend (java spring). 
I've set a few code for that, following many article.

1. **FirebaseServiceCredential.java**

This is for firebase connection, because i'm verifying using **[Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)**

```
    package com.nostratech.nostrafood.config;

    import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;

    @Slf4j
    @Configuration
    public class FirebaseServiceCredential {
    public void firebaseConnect() throws IOException {
        try {
            FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("resources/charity-firebase-adminsdk-ymwjh-61467z75ba.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://charity.firebaseio.com/")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance()).setPersistenceEnabled(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.debug("Trying to login to firebase failed. Reason: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

2. **GoogleSignInService.java**

This is code for [verifyIdToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens)

```
    package com.nostratech.nostrafood.service.base;

    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseToken;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    @Service
    public class GoogleSignInService {

        public void verifyToken(String idToken) throws FirebaseAuthException {
            FirebaseToken decodedToken = 
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken);
            String uid = decodedToken.getUid();
        }
    }
```

What should I do next for verify the token? I've read many article but still stuck dont know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

If `verifyIdToken()` returns without throwing an exception, then the token is verified. No other action is needed to verify an ID token. The return value (`FirebaseToken`) gives you access to the UID and the JWT claims associated with the authenticated user.